# I want to add pdf and excel buttons in printpreviewdialog page in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, printdocument, print-preview

I want to add pdf and excel buttons on the printpreviewdialog page in the link below. I did my work with the printdocument item in the Toolbox without using tools like iTextSharp. I want to add PDF, Excel and Close buttons.

Thanks.

**emphasized text:**

[image]

Comment: You can't change the `PrintPreviewDialog` much, if at all, but you can create your own form that contains the same `PrintPreviewControl` that it uses. That sounds like your best bet.